# file compression functions where did they come from

Tags: file, delphi, compression

This code uses: **TArchiveEntry**;
So, I really doubt this is not from **Zlib** Unit? because **TArchiveEntry** can be used without declaring the **Zlib** Unit.

```
var AE : TArchiveEntry;
```

```
AE.EntryType := aeFile;
AE.FileNameLen := Length(sr.Name);
AE.FileLength := sr.Size;
OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
OutStream.Write(sr.Name[1], Length(sr.Name));
// Write the file itself
TmpStream := TFileStream.Create(ADir + sr.Name, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
OutStream.CopyFrom(TmpStream, TmpStream.Size);
TmpStream.Free;
```

This is from **Zlib** Unit, without doubt.

```
var compr : TZCompressionStream;
```

```
for i := 0 to zFiles.Count-1 do
begin
  compr := TZCompressionStream.Create(mStream, zcDefault);
  compr.CopyFrom(infile,c);
  compr.Free;
end;
```

I wonder why, what there differences? I can't figure it out, there almost have the same performance.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking what is the difference between an apple and an orange?

Comment: Hello, I'm asking what is the difference between these two compression methods, and where did this TArchiveEntry came from(what unit) because I can't find it in any of the resource code of delphi, but when I used its fine. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `TArchiveEntry` type in the `System.ZLib` unit (or the `System.Zip` unit, for that matter). The first code snippet you show is a direct copy/paste of code from an old newsgroup posting that defines its own `TArchiveEntry` type above the snippet you copied:

[Re: How to use ZLib to zip up a folder in Delphi 2005???](http://comp.newsgroups.archived.at/lang.pascal.delphi.misc/200501/0501044987.html)

Comment: Yes, I know there is no TArchiveEntry in the Zlib or ZlibEx Unit, so what unit this TArchiveEntry came from? thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry, I figure it out, I didn't know that TArchiveEntry was only a (type packed record) call and was used  to combined or mix the files, not compression after all. thanks, sorry.

Comment: thanks, I will not use the TArchiveEntry for the compression or combining of files of any folder, If I used it, it will slow down the compression time, because TArchiveEntry first combined file bytes at it takes time for large files, I'll try to compress the folders and files directly with Zlib, got it.

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be:

> How do I determine which unit a symbol is defined in?

Once you have compiled the project, hover the cursor over the symbol and the IDE will display a hint which names the unit where the symbol is defined.

Or, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click to open the unit that declares the symbol in the editor.